# How to fully empty or delete VSTS package feed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

A year ago I created package feed in my account to publish for myself nuget packages. I don't need these packages because the whole project was re-organized and re-factored. I would like to clean up the package feed, to be able to publish further packages. To avoid naming conflicts and misunderstanding (myself a year ago can confuse myself now :D )I would like to delete these packages or empty the whole feed.

I cannot find any options to do so. Is there any way to do it beside select package - remove latest - reload page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way would be to delete the feed, wait 15 minutes for the feed name to be released, and re-create it.

You can delete the feed from the feed's settings screen (look for the gear icon in the top right corner)